# Associative arrays - create dynamically (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have form in Code Igniter and I want to use helper `form_dropdown()`. In order to do it I have to prepare associative array like this:

```
$options = array(
              'small'  => 'Samsung',
              'med'    => 'Apple',
              'large'   => 'HTC',
              'xlarge' => 'Nokia',
            );
```

But in this view this data are transferred from controller, which are taken from model, of course.

```
        $this->db->select('id');
        $query  = $this->db->get('ci_table1');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
           $data[] = $row; 
        };
    };

    $id_data['id'] = $data;

    $this->load->view('update_record_view', $id_data);
```

So, on the side of view I have the `foreach`-loop:

```
 foreach ($id as $row) 
          {
             // this I want to construct associative array
          }
```

Question is follow: how to create associative array at my case dynamically?

Comment: You did not supply enough information to answer this question. Where did your data come from? query()->result_array()?

Comment: Yes, you right - I've updated topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your code. But maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
    $this->db->select('id');
    $id_data['id'] = $this->db->get('ci_table1')->result_array(); 
    $this->load->view('update_record_view', $id_data);
```

and:

```
    $options = array();
    foreach ($id as $row) 
    {
        // this I want to construct associative array
        $options[ $row['id'] ] = ...;
    }
```

Comment: You don't understand my code, may be, becouse of this is my first CI-project and I use CI 1.7. But anyway - you code works and really I have array which I need. Thak you very much for help!

Comment: Ok, please flag my answer as the solution ;)